# Kotlin DSL issue: namespace and unitTests.returnDefaultValues

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I am migrating my project from Groovy DSL to Kotlin DSL and have two things I have not found a way to rewrite on Kotlin DSL.

Groovy DSL:

```
android {
  namespace "com.example"
}
```

Groovy DSL

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespace is resolved as:

```
android {
  namespace = "com.example.project"
  ...
}
```

Default values for unit test are resolved as:

```
android {
  ...
  testOptions {
    animationsDisabled = true
    unitTests {
      isReturnDefaultValues = true
    }
  }
}
```